# Item name / title when creating a folder

Tags: splistitem, folder

I am trying to create a list item with a folder content type by setting it's content type id to a folder content type id. The folder is created successfully but the title is set as 1_.000, 2_.000 etc.

I tried setting item["Title"] and item["Name"] to no avail.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not document library, righ?

If not this will do (not the best code I wrote but it works):

```
string folderName = "MyFolderName";

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mycoolsite/"))
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
        string rootUrl = list.RootFolder.Url;
        SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
        item["ContentType"] = "Folder";
        item.Update();
        SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(string.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.Url, item.DisplayName));
        folder.MoveTo(string.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.Url, folderName));
    }
}
```

As far as I know [SPFolder.MoveTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.moveto.aspx) is only option for folder renaming .

Or simply use this [Create Sub Folders in Lists Programmatically](http://vspug.com/stevekay72/2007/08/16/create-sub-folders-in-lists-programmatically/)

```
string folderName = "MyFolderName";

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mycoolsite/"))
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
        SPListItem item = list.AddItem("", SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, folderName);
        item.Update();
    }
}
```

And little explanation: First example is what question owner wants: Create item with Content type Folder and set/change its name. Second one is just adding folder to SPList.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit I have little update.

Answer (score 0):

try item.Title in your source code

Comment: Title property is always read-only.

Comment: item["Title"]="foldertitle" then item.Update(). It is possible to set title. Title is not read only

Comment: As I wrote in my post, I already tried item["Title"] but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new subfolder in a doc lib, this is how you do it:

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
web.Folders["ListName"].SubFolders.Add("FolderName");
```