# SharePoint 2013 Workflow create Folder (Problem with name / title)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I've got actually the same problem like in that post:
[Item name / title when creating a folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19968/item-name-title-when-creating-a-folder)

But I wanna fix it without a code solution.
Is there any chance to fix it with one SP 2013 Workflow? The problem is "only" the name field.... and I dont wanna start an SP2010 Workflow in the SP2013 WF

Here my Workflow:
[image]

But that's what I'm getting:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got now a little workaround for my problem, which I wanna share with you guys.

I created now a SP 2013 WF where Im getting the datefield from an other list via the HTTP Webservice. After that Im going to start an SP 2010 WF with the datafield as an parameter
This SP 2010 WF is creating an Folder which is called: JourMix_[Date] and two subfolders which are called: Agenda_[Date] & Protokoll_[Date].

After that the Listitem from a list is used to create a new item in the Agendafolder and in an other list. The last step is deleting the old item

If you wanna have more details just ask them.

Maybe someone could use this.

SP 2013 WF:
[image]

SP 2010 WF:
[image]
[image]

But actually I would love to figure out how this is possible with one SharePoint 2013 Workflow. Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

A detailed solution on how to solve this problem using only a single SharePoint 2013 workflow can be found in this post: [How to Create a Folder in a SharePoint 2013 List using a SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow](http://www.mariagraziamerlo.com/2016/01/17/how-to-create-a-folder-in-a-sharepoint-2013-list-using-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/)

The proposed solution works both for SharePoint 2013 On-Premises and Online (Office 365) and uses only SharePoint Designer 2013 built-in actions.